# synchronize a sqlite database to server iphonesdk

Tags: iphone, sqlite, synchronization

I have an sqlite database in my app and would like to synchronize it with an sql database on a server. (http)
any ideas about how to do this?

Comment: Synchronization is a fairly complex topic and depends heavily on the data you have. Can you give a bit more information about what you're doing and answer the following: Do you want 2 way synchronization? Will multiple clients sync with the same data?

Comment: multiple clients will sync with the same data. i dont think i'll be needing a two way sync.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the best way I can think of is to use some kind of REST webservice with JSON.
The just call the url, parse the JSON into the database.